# line 63: syntax error near unexpected token `;' in bashrc

Tags: macos, bash, bash-scripting, bashrc

I have bash function of:

```
myworkhomebrewapp(){ atom $HOMEBREW_FRONTEND; atom $HOMEBREW_BACKEND; workon homebrew_server; cd $HOMEBREW_BACKEND; python manage.py runserver & ; /usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" "file:///Users/cchilders/projects/good_brews/frontend/index.html" ;}
```

But it causes error

```
$ src
-bash: /Users/cchilders/.bash_profile: line 63: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
-bash: /Users/cchilders/.bash_profile: line 63: `myworkhomebrewapp(){ atom $HOMEBREW_FRONTEND; atom $HOMEBREW_BACKEND; workon homebrew_server; cd $HOMEBREW_BACKEND; python manage.py runserver & ; /usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" "file:///Users/cchilders/projects/good_brews/frontend/index.html" ;}'
```

I don't know what causes error, but commenting that line out fixes it. Where is my bash function broken please? Thank you

One solution:

I was able to fix the issue by splitting new lines in my .bashrc, which isn't what I wanted:

```
myworkhomebrewapp(){
    atom $HOMEBREW_FRONTEND
    atom $HOMEBREW_BACKEND
    workon homebrew_server
    cd $HOMEBREW_BACKEND
    python manage.py runserver &
    sleep 5
    /usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" "file://$HOMEBREW_FRONTEND/index.html"
}
```

Comment: It's the semicolon after the ampersand that is causing the error (pity that `bash` doesn't report the column as well as the line number): blank statements are not allowed. You can separate statements by either `;` or `&` (as well as other separators), but not both. Just typing `;` into `bash` gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### syntax error near unexpected token `;`

Running your one liner through [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) throws up the following warning/errors (warnings are green, errors are red):

[image]

Removing the `;` from `python manage.py runserver & ;` removes the error, leaving just the warnings:

[image]

---

#### ShellCheck - A shell script static analysis tool

> ShellCheck is a GPLv3 tool that gives warnings and suggestions for
>   bash/sh shell scripts:
>
> Screenshot of a terminal showing problematic shell script lines
>   highlighted.
>
> [image]
>
> The goals of ShellCheck are
>
> - To point out and clarify typical beginner's syntax issues that cause a shell to give cryptic error messages.
> - To point out and clarify typical intermediate level semantic problems that cause a shell to behave strangely and
>     counter-intuitively.
> - To point out subtle caveats, corner cases and pitfalls that may cause an advanced user's otherwise working script to fail under future
>     circumstances.

Source [ShellCheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Crossed with you yet again! Thanks for the site - I didn't know about it.

Comment: @afh Hehe. If it wasn't for that site I wouldn't have been able to answer the question - I'm no `bash` expert :)

Comment: I found it by replacing each `;` with `&&` in turn. When the error report changed to `&&` I then knew which semicolon was at fault.

Comment: @afh Oh, that's a nice debugging technique.